# Django: Subclassing UserCreationForm: doesn't have get_user() method?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-custom-user

I created a custom user in Django by subclassing the normal User model. This user's only difference is that it doesn't have a username. Now, I'm trying to use the built in Django UserCreationForms to log users in. I subclassed UserCreationForm and created SignUpForm, which doesn't have a username field.

My control flow is as follows:
1) Check to see if input form is valid
2) if it is, get the user out of the form
3) save the form (thereby saving the user)
4) log the user in

However, when I try to get a user out of the SignUpForm instance, it throws me this error: AttributeError at /user/signup
'SignUpForm' object has no attribute 'get_user'

I don't understand this because SignUpForm is directly subclassed from UserCreationForm, which implements the get_user() method. My code for views.py is below:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from django.db import models
    User = get_user_model()


    # Create your views here.

    class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Enter a valid email address.')
        username = None

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST': # if sending data to the server
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)# creates form from request data
            if form.is_valid():
    #            print("form valid")
                user = form.get_user() # ERROR IS HERE
                form.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/manager')
            else:
                print("error")
        else:
            print("Get request asked for")
            form = SignUpForm()
            return render(request, 'user/signup.html', {'form': form}) # return rendered form
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to excuse me, I was reading the documentation wrong. The UserCreationForm doesn't have a get_user() method, but instead returns a user when the save method is called. Do I agree with this implementation? No, but I suppose it helps to limit the amount of methods in the first place.